# Where can I meet recruiters (new to the field)?

Tags: management, recruitment, events, recruiting, off-site-events

Just started my first recruiting job and want to know what types of events can I go to to meet other recruiters?

Also wondering what types of events recruiters go to to find candidates (obviously this is also a place I can meet other recruiters)? Things like university hiring events, etc?

I am in the tech industry in silicon valley. I am also looking for FREE events (not expensive conferences).

Comment: What field are you in and where are you?

Comment: @hranainterhr please consider what IASNL says, and include your location and industry if possible, to help narrow down your options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just started my first recruiting job and want to know what types of events can I go to to meet other recruiters?

Check for **Job Fairs** near you. Usually those are useful events where you can be exposed to several industries and companies of your interest, as well as a place where you can get a few new contacts to call and attempt a job offer.

You can also try looking for jobs **through a Contract Agency**. This is also a viable solution, as they can do the searching for you (they tend to have several contacts) and find potential recruiters willing to hire you and in companies and positions you want.

Also, if you work on the *Software Industry* you can try going to **Hackathons, Conventions, and similar events**, where recruiters usually go to "catch" promising candidates.

In that case, you could also try using the [Stackoverflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) to find developer jobs that fit your needs and interests. Not that I have used it, but the SE guys and several users seem to be content about its effectiveness.

Comment: I seen recruiters attend open events like a dev con type event.

Comment: @Dan true, but OP doesn't indicated that he works on the Software Industry, so I kept my answer as general as possible. Enhancing to include other options